# How do I remove certain indexes from each list within a list of lists

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, indexing

So to create my array of lists I have this

```
def file_processor(filename):
       #create an empty list
    cities_list = []
    try:
        file_read = open(filename, "r")
        for line in file_read:
            split_line = line.split(",")
            cities_list.append(split_line)
        file_read.close()
        return cities_list
    except IOError:
        print("File was not found.")
```

I need to create a new array of lists but with only the 0 index and the 7th index, 
but everything I am doing isn't working.

This is what I have so far for my duplicate list

```
def blackWhiteSeglist(filename):
        b_w_list= []
    try:
        file_read = open(filename, "r")
        for line in file_read:
            split_line = line.split(",")
            b_w_list.append(split_line)
        file_read.close()
        for list in b_w_list:
            for line in list:
                b_w_list.pop(1:6,8:12)
        return b_w_list
    except IOError:
        print("File was not found.")
```

There are a total of 13 indexes (0-12) but i just need the 0 and 7

Comment: you can't `pop` elements using indices like that.  You can only pop one item at a time.

Comment: I would suggest using `with open(filename) as file_read:` syntax instead.

Answer (score 2):

Take only what you need:

```
b_w_list.append([split_line[0], split_line[7]])
```

The whole function could look like this:

```
def blackWhiteSeglist(filename):
    b_w_list= []
    with open(filename, "r") as file_read:
        for line in file_read:
            split_line = line.split(",")
            b_w_list.append([split_line[0], split_line[7]])
    return b_w_list
```

Comment: this will append a list within a list though.

Comment: @KronoS `split_line` should be a list and I take two elements from it and create a new list.

Comment: `append` will take the `b_w_list` and append the list to it... therefore you'll have a list within a list.  `[].append([1, 2])` will return `[[1, 2]]`

Comment: @KronoS I think thats what OP wants.

Comment: @KronoS Yes. Isn't what `b_w_list.append(split_line)` does? It takes the list `split_line` and appends it to the list `b_w_list`. Now instead of the full  list `split_line`, I take only a partial list with two elements.

Comment: @KronoS No Problem. :)  Such things happen.